# Excel Data Imported as '15/2, Macro to convert to number?

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I'm importing data from an API into Excel via power query.

As some of the data is in fractions this is causing a bit of a nightmare. I can't use 'number' because of this and it throws an error, so I have to import as text.

When doing so the data imports as below, with a "'" in front:

[image: Data Excel]

As I need the data to update each minute, and then run formulas on it, I need this to be a number. What's the easiest way (either macro to convert to number from '15/2) or to fix Power Query and allow for it to import/convert fractions? (That would be perfect!)

Comment: Are you wanting it to display as the result of this equation--in this case 7.5?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, thanks.

Comment: Just curious, what process do you use to update the data each minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a macro to use (assuming your screenshot has the correct column placements).  The only adjustment you need to make is adjust "intLastRow" with the last row of your data.

```
Sub SO()
    Dim intLastRow As Integer, strIn As String
    intLastRow = 100
    For I = 2 To intLastRow
        For t = 4 To 21
            If InStr(1, Cells(I, t).Value, "/") > 0 Then
                strIn = Cells(I, t).Value
                Cells(I, t).Value = Val(Left(strIn, InStr(1, strIn, "/") - 1)) / Val(Right(strIn, Len(strIn) - InStr(1, strIn, "/")))
            Else
                Cells(I, t).Value = Val(Cells(I, t).Value)
            End If
        Next t
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Lovely, works perfectly for the fractions. Is there a way of combining this with the code below, to work for the whole numbers with just an apostrophe before?

Comment: I made a small edit to my code to include an else statement (to accommodate for those whole numbers).

Comment: Perfect, you're a live safer!

Comment: Sorry to be an absolute pain, I've just expanded to scraping the entire data from the API. Everything is now downloading without apostrophes, i.e. either as numbers correctly or as "1/2".
Is there any macro you can suggest that simply turns the fractions into numbers? I have Column A as the name, then to Column B to Column S with data (some with fractions).

Comment: This macro should perform that function.  You'll have to adjust it to work with all columns (so another for loop), but to convert from fraction to number it just looks for the "/".  And unless I'm mistaken, if a cell contains the "/", it should be a string.

Comment: Ok it works, if I just change the 5's in the Macro to say 4's.

How do I get it to loop from say 4 to 21?

Comment: Correct.  And like I said in a previous comment, if you want it to work on all columns without having to make that manual change, you can set up another FOR loop to run through them along with the rows.

Comment: I understand completely, just unsure how to edit the macro correctly to make a loop for 4 to 21. Many Thanks

Comment: Check the edited code, the FOR loop for the columns has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can then step through a selection of cells and check to see if the prefix character for each cell is an apostrophe. If it is, then all you need to do is have the macro do the equivalent of manually retyping the contents of the cell, in the following manner:

```
For Each c In Selection
    If c.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
        c.Value = c.Value
    End If
Next c
```

Note that the macro checks what is in the PrefixCharacter property. This property can be read in VBA, but it cannot be changed directly. That is why the macro needs to use the seemingly simple line to assign the value of each cell back into the cell—essentially retyping the contents.

For complete guide see this:
http://excel.tips.net/T003332_Searching_for_Leading_Apostrophes.html

This is my own code:

```
Public Sub tryit()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 20 'repeat until your last record
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        If .Cells(i, 5).PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
            MsgBox "removing 1 apostrophe..."
            .Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & .Cells(i, 5)
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

And... Voila!

Comment: Well, that was 1 way to do it, you may apply another way though... I think this is the simplest way... hope this is the answer you want

Comment: It works for everything, apart from the 15/2, which remains the same.

Comment: If you remove the apostrophe it turns into a date, it's almost like a macro is needed to remove the ' and replace with =, then press enter.

Comment: Try to change the format, i've tried this before, it almost likely no change at all (as it displayed), but you can really notice that the apostrophe is already gone. It is officially a number, a fraction number :D

Comment: I see that another good answer just posted... This is what you want, about replacing apostrophe with an equal sign (' into =)  I've just edited my answer as your alternative way, perhaps :D

Comment: Sorry to be an absolute pain, I've just expanded to scraping the entire data from the API. Everything is now downloading without apostrophes, i.e. either as numbers correctly or as "1/2".
Is there any macro you can suggest that simply turns the fractions into numbers? I have Column A as the name, then to Column B to Column S with data (some with fractions).

Comment: Please kindly review my edited answer. You might like to remove the IF part (and the msgbox, of course :D)

Answer (score 1):

The Power Query solution to parsing math expressions as a number is simple!

Just add a custom final step `Table.TransformColumns(SomeLastStep, {}, Expression.Evaluate)`. This works by running text input like `9` or `15/2` as a tiny program that returns a number.

[image]

(You might also want to convert the columns to number afterwards.)

View > Advanced Editor for full example:

```
let
    SomeLastStep = #table( {"data1", "data2"}, { {"9", "15/2"}, {"10", "8"}, {"11", "10"}, {"11", "10"} } ),
    Custom1 = Table.TransformColumns(SomeLastStep, {}, Expression.Evaluate),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom1,{{"data1", type number}, {"data2", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

---

BTW, this is different than the dreaded `eval()` in scripting languages: without any arguments, `Expression.Evaluate` will not have access to any functions in scope and so can't have any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is the macro vba code you want to see for your another problem:

```
Public Sub tryit()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20 'repeat until your last record
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & .Cells(i, 5)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```